# How to group the array of objects with a property in typescript?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, java-8

I want to group the array of object in typescript. I did it in traditional or imperative way as follows:

```
     public datas: Data[];
     public dtoMap: Map<String, DataDTO[]> = new Map<String, DataDTO[]>();


 private groupBy(): void {
            for (let item of this.datas) {            
                let valueList: DataDTO[] = this.dtoMap.get(item.type);
                if (isUndefined(valueList) || valueList === null) {
                    valueList = new Array<DataDTO>();
                }
                valueList.push(convertToDTO(item));
                this.dtoMap.set(item.type, valueList);
            }
}
```

But in Java, I wrote similar method as follow:

```
public Map<String, List<DataDTO>> getDataMap(String defId, List<Data> datas) {
 return datas.stream().map(item -> convertToDTO(defId, item)).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DataDTO::getType, Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Can you help to improve the typescript method? What is the best way to group the array of objects with a property in TypeScript? Thanks

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()` is completely redundant.

Comment: @shmosel, I just copied my code and edited here. Thanks for highlighting it

Comment: Is your alignment correct? It looks so weird. Where is the function?

Comment: You also don't need to specify `toList()` in the `groupingBy()` collector; it's the default.

Answer (score 6):

usually, for any kind of complex transformation in JS, I use lodash which can be used in TS as well. Hope the below helps you. The 'property' is the key by which you want to group the collection of items.

```
    import * as _ from 'lodash';

export class A {
 public datas: Data[];

private groupBy(): void {
           let groupedItems: any[] = _.groupBy(datas, 'property');
}
}
```

Ashley